$\left[\dfrac 12\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right]=k-1$
Consider this $\left[\dfrac 12\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}\frac 1{\sqrt n}\right]$ where $[\cdot]$ is the greatest integer function.
I had observed that its value is $(k-1)$ by putting $k=2,3,4,$ upto $5$ and pressing my calculator button.
But could not prove it manually.
I thought about this inequalities like $n>\sqrt n\implies \frac 1{\sqrt n}>\frac 1 n$ but got nothing. Some clever approach is needed here  Which I am unable to find.

you can estimate the difference between $\sum_{n} 1/\sqrt{n} - \int 1/\sqrt{x} dx$, try to squeeze the gap as much as possible.

See the almost identical question here with interesting answers in particular by @Claude Leibovici (reference found using approach0 formula searching engine)

Here is an elementary approach.
We know
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n = \frac 1{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt n}$$
Hence
$$\frac 1{2\sqrt{n+1}} < \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n < \frac 1{2\sqrt{n}}$$
It follows, on one hand
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}\frac 1{2\sqrt n} > \sum_{n=1}^{k^2}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n) = \sqrt{k^2 +1} - 1 > k-1$$
On the other hand, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}\frac 1{2\sqrt n} = \frac 12 + \sum_{\color{blue}{{n=2}}}^{k^2}\frac 1{2\sqrt n}= \frac 12 + \sum_{\color{blue}{n=1}}^{\color{blue}{k^2-1}}\frac 1{2\sqrt{\color{blue}{n+1}}}$$ $$< \frac 12 + \sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)= \frac 12 + k - 1= k-\frac 12$$
All together
$$\boxed{k-1 < \sum_{n=1}^{k^2}\frac 1{2\sqrt n} < k-\frac 12}$$

As $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is strictly decreasing, for every integer $n$ we have $$f(n)=\displaystyle\int_{n}^{n+1}f(n)\,dx> \displaystyle\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)\,dx$$
and $$f(n)=\displaystyle\int_{n}^{n+1}f(n)\,dx< \displaystyle\int_{n-1}^{n}f(x)\,dx$$
It follows from the first inequality that $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}f(n)> \displaystyle\int_{1}^{k^2+1} f(x)\,dx=\displaystyle\int_{1}^{k^2+1}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{k^2+1}-1$$
As $k^2+1\geq k^2$, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}f(n)> \sqrt{k^2}-1=k-1$.
And from the second inequality, $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}f(n)< \displaystyle\int_{0}^{k^2} f(x)\,dx=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{k^2}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx=\sqrt{k^2}=k$$
This proves that $$\left\lfloor \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\right\rfloor=k-1,$$
as desired.

Let $g(a) = \sum_{k=1}^a 1/\sqrt{k}$ and $I(a)= \int_1^a 1/\sqrt{x} \, dx = 2(\sqrt{a}-1)$
Then, we can graphically check:
$$ I(a+1) \le g(a) \le 1 + I(a)$$

In the first graph, for $a=4$, $g(a)$ corresponds to the yellow+orange bars, $I(a)$ to the red+orange area (the additional $1$ term comes from the yellow square.
In the second graph, $g(a)$ again corresponds to the yellow+orange bars, and in orange we have $I(a+1)$.
This means
$$ \sqrt{k^2+1}-1 \le \frac12 g(k^2) \le \frac12 + (k-1)$$
or
$$ k-1 \le \frac12 g(k^2) \le (k-1)+\frac12$$

If you are comfortable with generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_k=\dfrac 12\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{k^2}\frac 1{\sqrt n}=\frac 12 H_{k^2}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ whose asymptotic is
$$S_k=k+\frac{1}{2}\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1
   }{4 k}-\frac{1}{48k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^7}\right)$$ where
$\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=-1.46035$.
Using instead the Euler-MacLaurin summation, we should have
$$S_k=k+C+\frac{1}{4 k}-\frac{1}{48
   k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^7}\right)$$
and, for this level of expansion,
$$C=-\frac{6136167}{8388608}=-0.731488$$ which is extremely close to the theoretical value.
Now, take the floor of the result to obtain the rhs.

Without an explicit bound on the error term this proves only that the inequality holds for sufficiently large $k$.
